# Symfony2 use of class

Tags: php, class, symfony, namespaces, class-reference

I have a file Orders.php and I want to use class "Test" functions in it. The problem is that the class file is in a project root folder, but I can't use it.

orders.php:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Command;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Test;

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', '4000M');
    $test = new \Test(true);
    exit;
}
```

And class file test.php is:

```
<?php

namespace Test;

class Test
{
     public function __construct($connect = null, $query = null)
     {
        if ($connect)
        {
            $this->connect();
        }

        if ($query)
        {
            $this->query($query);
        }
     }
}
```

Now the test.php class file is in project root folder. And the orders.php file is in public_html\project\src\AppBundle\Command\order.php

How should I use the class test if it's in the root of the project or any other directory? I write the namespace with the "/" so it should be refering to the root directory, no?

Comment: Why can't you put test.php under AppBundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to autoload `test.php` if you want to load it from outside an already defined PSR-0/PSR-4 direcotry. You can [autoload single files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) by updating your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/test.php"]
    }
}
```

After updating `composer.json`, you'll need to run the following command:

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: My autoload part in composer.json:

    "autoload": {
  "files": ["src/test.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },

But it class test is still not found after the dumpautoload

And the file itself is in src/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I didn't have to use the namespace in my class file. Also autoloader helped. Thank you.